# How to Detect When the Enter Key was Pressed using F sharp (F#)

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, f#

How do I detect when the Enter key was pressed when using F sharp (F#) and XAML?

I have seen articles on how to do it in C# (like [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/ms752054%28v=vs.110%29.aspx%29)) , but didn't find anything online while searching for F#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a console application you can do this, which is very similar to the C# code.

```
open System
let keyStroke = Console.ReadKey() 
if keyStroke.Key.Equals(ConsoleKey.Enter) then
    printfn "Enter pressed"
else
    printfn "%c pressed" keyStroke.KeyChar
```

In wpf you can get information about key presses by registering for the PreviewKeyDown, or similar events. [How do I run some simple C# code for a given keypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098892/how-do-i-run-some-simple-c-sharp-code-for-a-given-keypress)

Answer (score 0):

Well I've never coded in F# before but I started using XAML recently and I'm certain you can add a KeyDown EventHabdler in the XAML code and navigate to the generated function. That function will detect a key press if the object has focus. This is normally presented using buttons. Imagine this code in your XAML

```
<Page
    //....generated stuff>

    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="Button1"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

You can then change it to:

```
<Page
    //....generated stuff>

    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="Button1" KeyDown="Function Name"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Then you'll right click "Function Name" and select go to Navigate to Event Handler. The compiler will take you to the newly generated function and you'll be able to write code in it that will run everytime you press a key will the Button has focus. Though you normally make the grid be the holder of the function, that way when the grid or anything in it has focus the event will fire and run the code.

Comment: If this isn't what you were looking for I answered a similar question before but my answer was used for Window Events rather than XAML Events. They're kind off the same but Window Events fire off no matter what has focus. The link is [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17736867/2480591). It's C++/CX but maybe you'll get an idea of how to implemet it. :)